# Not able to launch Spyder version 4.1.1

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I recently created a new environment with `Anaconda Navigator` and installed in it the `Spyder IDE` version `4.1.1`. The problem is, whenever I try to launch it (via `Anaconda Navigator`), it raises me the following exception, and doesn´t launch at all:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\marco\anaconda3\envs\Webscraping_env\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())

File "C:\Users\marco\anaconda3\envs\Webscraping_env\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 205, in main
mainwindow.main()

File "C:\Users\marco\anaconda3\envs\Webscraping_env\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3700, in main
mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)

File "C:\Users\marco\anaconda3\envs\Webscraping_env\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3556, in run_spyder
main.setup()

File "C:\Users\marco\anaconda3\envs\Webscraping_env\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 1217, in setup
self.apply_shortcuts()

File "C:\Users\marco\anaconda3\envs\Webscraping_env\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3207, in apply_shortcuts
self.help.show_intro_message()

File "C:\Users\marco\anaconda3\envs\Webscraping_env\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\help\plugin.py", line 456, in show_intro_message
shortcut_editor, "\n\n", prefs)

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

But when I go to the root environment and try to launch from there `Spyder` version `4.0.1`, it launchs with no issues.

Comment: Please run `spyder --reset` in the Anaconda Prompt to fix this.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba It worked! Thank you!